# Obtener el ID de un INSERT para un UPDATE en Mysql y PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql

Tengo una query que hace un insert en mi BD

```
$query = "INSERT INTO pedidos (id, usuario, operador, monto, nro_transf, banco_emisor, banco_destino, fecha_transf, ci_nro_cuenta, status_pedido) 
VALUES(null, '$usua', '$operador', '$monto', '$nro_transf', '$banco_emisor', '$banco_destino', '$fecha_transf', '$ci_nro_cuenta', '$status_pedido')";
```

en la estructura de mi BD el id es un autoincrement pero inmediatamente se ejecute el insert

```
if (mysqli_query($db, $query))
```

Quiero hacer un update de otra tabla, en donde tengo varias columnas pero básicamente solo me interesa cambiar los valores de la columna status y relación, en el caso de la columna status solo lo voy a pasar de 1 a 2 y en la columna relación deseo tomar el valor del id que fue asignado por Mysql en el insert anterior y no se como recuperar esa variable.

```
$sql = "UPDATE recargar SET
    status = 2,
    relacion = '$idDelInsert'
    WHERE
    idusuario = '$usua' AND status = 1";
```

Se que puedo hacer un query select  entre los query insert y update aplicando un `ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1` para seleccionar el ultimo dato de este usuario para recuperar la variable id que asigno Mysql pero mi consulta es saber si hay otra forma mas fácil de hacerlo.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Otra opción sería la función [mysqli_insert_id()](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.insert-id.php) para obtener el ID de la última consulta. *(Ojo que el campo ID, deberá tener como atributo `AUTO_INCREMENT`)*

```
if (mysqli_query($db, $query)){
   echo $db->insert_id;  // obtenemos el último id
   /* Query Update*/
}
```

> Además no olvidar, utilizar [sentencias preparadas para tus querys](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)v ya que
>   reciben datos del usuario. Y así prevenir ataques.

Comment: Que pasa si es una tabla trasanccional que recibe muchos insert? el ultimo ID seria para esta transaccion o el ultimo ID de la base?

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez la primera opción,  tomando como base la conexión con la que se realiza el insert.